# Suitable Indo-European related graduate program for a linguist

Tags: masters, linguistics

I have got a Masters in Linguistics. I like ancient Indo-European and comparative IE Linguistics. I want to get another master in Europe. In current time, which master or PhD programs in IE studies needs student with a linguistics background? I mean programmes which mostly rely on linguistics principles rather than, for example philological methods. It's ok If the program restricted to only one branch of IE languages (for example Germanic).

Comment: Why another masters? What will it give you? Wouldn't a doctorate be better for your career?

Comment: @Buffy. Because I don't have background in IE studies. Can I directly apply for such PhD programs?

Comment: That depends on where. It seems more natural, however, with a masters in linguistics already. It is worth an exploration anyway.

Comment: I've never heard of a linguistics program that did not include anything Indo-European.